# In a metric space $X$, is it possible for $r>0$ and two distinct points $u$ and $v$ in $X$ to have $B(u,r)=B(v,r)$?

Tags: real-analysis

Furthermore, is this possible in Euclidean space $R^{n}$ or a normed linear space?

My attemption:

Consider the discrete metric and $r = 1$, then we have for any $u,v\in X$, $B(u,r) = B(v,r)$

The result does not hold in a norme liner space.

Defien $x = (r-\varepsilon)\cdot \frac{v-u}{\rho(v,u)} + v$

Then we can find $\rho(x,v) < r$ and $\rho(x,u) = 1+r-\varepsilon > r$ so $x\in B(v,r)$ but $x\notin B(u,r)$

Is my method correct?  Any advice would be apprecaite!

Comment: Yes, it is a perfect answer.

Comment: Thank you! @geetha290krm